# Prevent gzip with HTML <META> tag

Tags: html, gzip, meta-tags

I have a straight HTML page that I want to use for diagnostic checks so I would like to reload it each time it is referenced and load the string of characters.  Forcing reload is relatively easy, but I have not been able to prevent gzip encoding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
     <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
     <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Encoding" CONTENT="text/html text/plain *;q=0">
```

I would strongly prefer to do this with HTML and not put in a server-side workaround.

Thanks.

PS: If the NO-CACHE does not work, you can easily force a reload by appending something to the URL.  I use

```
 var time=new Date().getTime();
 URL=URL+"?time="+time;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gzip encoding is handled by the server. It cannot be prevented by changing the document.